# jQuery Toggle Function based on DIV IDs

Tags: jquery

Hey so I'm trying to create a custom toggle jQuery function for an click event.

The HTML structured like this:

```
//These are the clickable boxes, CSS is taking care of the div's as squares//
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_1">1</div>
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_2">2</div>
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_3">3</div>

//Hidden div's (through class style display:none;) boxes that correspond to the clickable boxes above//
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_1">Hi</div>
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_2">Mello</div>
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_3">Rock</div>

//jQuery to make hidden div boxes toggle
$('.span_2 > div').click(function () {

           var $colToShow = $(this).attr('data-col-name');
           $('#' + $colToShow).toggleClass('toggle_col');
       });
```

All this works. The hidden boxes toggle visible once the class is removed as their corresponding div boxes are clicked. But what I want to add is that when a click event happens on another one of the clickable div boxes, the original box that became visible will become invisible again and the new visible div will take it's space. This is what I tried to do:

```
//jQuery adapted from the code before//
$('.span_2 > div').click(function () {
           var group = $('div[id^="hid"]'); //Create an array of hidden div boxes using the id//
           if(i=0;i<group.length;i++){ //Progress through each div and check to see if it's not hidden by the class//
              if(!group[i].hasClass('toggle_col')){ //It if isn't hidden make it hidden by toggling class//
                  group[i].toggleClass('toggle_col');
              }
           }


           var $colToShow = $(this).attr('data-col-name'); 
           $('#' + $colToShow).toggleClass('toggle_col');//Now make corresponding hidden div based on clickable box div appear//
       });
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Is `$('.span_2 > div')` correct? There are no descendent div's within `span_2` divs

Comment: It's only a piece of a code, so it does actually have descendants. I just didn't include them because they weren't relevant to what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You where close... try this..

```
$('.span_2 > div').click(function () {
           // add the toggle_col class to all of the elements with 
           // an id starting with hid_ if they have a common parent then you can
           // add that as part of the selector to scope the behavior a little better

           $('div[id^=hid_]').addClass('toggle_col');
           var $colToShow = $(this).attr('data-col-name');
           $('#' + $colToShow).toggleClass('toggle_col');
});
```

Comment: Yea that works. I definitely took the hard way around this lol. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just hide all the div's first and then show the corresponding clicked div? Rather than toggling class, just use the `show()` method to display the hidden div:

```
//These are the clickable boxes, CSS is taking care of the div's as squares//
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_1">1</div>
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_2">2</div>
<div class="span_2" data-col-name="hid_3">3</div>

//Hidden div's (through class style display:none;) boxes that correspond to the clickable boxes above//
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_1">Hi</div>
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_2">Mello</div>
<div class="toggle_col" id="hid_3">Rock</div>

//jQuery to make hidden div boxes toggle
$('.span_2 > div').click(function () {

    $('.toggle_col').hide();
    var $colToShow = $(this).attr('data-col-name');
    $('#' + $colToShow).show();
});
```